# Python shift with alphabet

Tags: python, decode, shift

```
def menu():
    choice = input("Press 1 to encode, 2 to decode, 9 to exit ")
    return choice

def makeKeycode(message):
    key = input("What is the key? ").upper()
    length = len(message)
    keycode = ""
    counter = 0
    while length >0:
        if counter == len(key):
            counter = 0
        keycode = keycode + key[counter]
        counter = counter + 1
        length = length - 1
    print(keycode)
    return keycode

def enterMessage():
    message = input("What is the message ").upper()
    return message

def encodeMessage(message, keycode):
    ciphertext =""
    alphabet= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTUVWXYZ"
    for i in range (len(message)):
        character = message[i]
        charCode = alphabet.find(character)
        keycodeChar =keycode[i]
        keyLetter = alphabet.find(keycodeChar)
        position = (charCode + keyLetter)%25
        cipherLetter = alphabet[position]
        ciphertext =ciphertext + cipherLetter
    return ciphertext

def decodeMessage(ciphertext,keycode):
    ciphertext =""
    alphabet= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTUVWXYZ"
    for i in range (len(ciphertext)):
        character = ciphertext[i]
        charCode = alphabet.find(character)
        keycodeChar =keycode[i]
        keyLetter = alphabet.find(keycodeChar)
        position = (charCode - keyLetter)%25
        cipherLetter = alphabet[position]
        ciphertext =ciphertext - cipherLetter
    return message

def enterCipher ():
    ciphertext = input("Enter the text to be decoded")
    return ciphertext

def encode():
    message = enterMessage()
    keycode = makeKeycode(message)
    ciphertext = encodeMessage(message,keycode)
    print(ciphertext)
def decode():

    keycode = makeKeycode(ciphertext)
    message = decodeMessage(ciphertext, keycode)
    print (message)   

def main():
    MyDictionary=("A:1","B:2","C:3","D:4","E:5","F:6","G:7","H:8","I:9","J:10","K:11","L:12","M:13","N:14","O:15","P:16","Q:17","R:18","S:19","T:20","U:21","V:22","W:23","X:24","Y:25","X:26")
    print (MyDictionary)
    choice = 0
    while choice !=9:
        choice = int(menu())

        if choice == 1:
            encode()
        elif choice == 2:
            decode()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Hi, I cant get my code to work, my encode function works but i am struggling to fix my decode function. I dont understand where i am going wrong. I want to be able to decode the message i will have encoded, but this doesn't work as the decode function stops the program. Have I made an error in the coding? Thanks for all the help
Regards

Comment: Well, here's a question, What if your encoded message is "11" is that a "K" or "AA" ?

Comment: What error are you getting when you say that your decode message stops the program? What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post. Note that once you post a question or answer to this site, those posts become part of the collective efforts of others who have also contributed to that content. Posts that are potentially useful to others should not be removed except under extraordinary circumstances. Even if the post is no longer useful to the original author, that information is still beneficial to others who may run into similar problems in the future - this is the underlying philosophy of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

```
def decodeMessage(ciphertext,keycode):
    ciphertext =""
```

It appears that you are resetting ciphertext to a null string. as a result, your `len(ciphertext)` is 0 which means you ae not doing anything.

python 2.75

```
sig = 'abcd'
def test(sig):
    sig = ""
    print 'sig = ', sig

>>> test(sig)
    sig = ''
>>> print sig
    'abcd'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am finding two problems with your decode message function:

```
def decodeMessage(ciphertext,keycode):
    ciphertext =""
    alphabet= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTUVWXYZ"
    for i in range (len(ciphertext)):
        character = ciphertext[i]
        charCode = alphabet.find(character)
        keycodeChar =keycode[i]
        keyLetter = alphabet.find(keycodeChar)
        position = (charCode - keyLetter)%25
        cipherLetter = alphabet[position]
        ciphertext =ciphertext - cipherLetter
    return message
```

The first issue that I found was the fact that you pass in ciphertext to decodeMessage as a mandatory parameter and then you change the value of ciphertext to "" (an empty string). I would recommend changing the ciphertext in the parameters to something like "ct" to prevent that overlap.

The second issue I found was the fact you return `message`, but you don't perform any action on message. When running this program, you'll get a global error because `message` is not global yet you're calling `message` in the local scope without having defined it locally.

Now, onto another matter: Your encode method doesn't encode anything correctly. Look at the following output:

```
Press 1 to encode, 2 to decode, 9 to exit 1
What is the message some
What is the key? 18
YNLD
Press 1 to encode, 2 to decode, 9 to exit 1
What is the message some
What is the key? 5
YNLD
Press 1 to encode, 2 to decode, 9 to exit 1
What is the message some
What is the key? 1
YNLD
```

All 'some's get encoded to 'YNLD' regardless of the key. To cipher something using a Caesar Cypher, you're going to want to use ords and chrs. Ord makes the character numerical, Chr makes the number into a letter. Consider the following function made in Python 3, for example:

```
from string import ascii_letters
def cypher_letter(letter, key):
    if letter not in ascii_letters: #commas, question marks, etc
        return letter 
    if letter.islower(): #lowercase and uppercase have differing ord values
        lower, upper = ord('a'), ord('z') # values: 97 to 122 
    elif letter.isupper():
        lower, upper = ord('A'), ord('Z') # values: 65 to 90
    else:
        print("Something went wrong.") #probably didn't enter valid letters

    cypher = ord(letter) + key #if key is "1" and letter is 'a', 97 + 1
    if cypher < lower: cypher += 26 #26 letters in alphabet, this is for looping
    if cypher > upper: cypher -= 26 #back around if it exceeds upper,lower limits
    return chr(cypher) #chr(98) = 'b'
```

The following code:

```
cyphered_words = []
keys = [18, 5, 1]
for key in keys:
    encoded = ""
    for letter in 'some':
        encoded += (cypher_letter(letter, key)) #to cypher we pass the key
    print(encoded)
    cyphered_word.append(encoded)
```

Outputs this:

```
Kgewlzafy hjwllq dgfy, oalz ugehdwp dwllwjk!
Xtrjymnsl uwjyyd qtsl, bnym htruqjc qjyyjwx!
Tpnfuijoh qsfuuz mpoh, xjui dpnqmfy mfuufst!
```

Cyphering and decyphering is almost the same thing. It's like they're yin and yang or something, so the decypher function would look like:

```
def decrypt_message(message, key):
    decyphered_text = ""
    for letter in message:
        decyphered_text += cypher_letter(letter, (key*-1)) #to decypher we pass the negative key 
    return decyphered_text
```

And a loop to decrypt our 3 'some's:

```
for count, word in enumerate(cyphered_words):
    print(decrypt_message_k(word, keys[count]))
```

And the output:

```
Something pretty long, with complex letters!
Something pretty long, with complex letters!
Something pretty long, with complex letters!
```

I hope this helps you get on the right track.